# passing string from IEnumerator to void

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, void, ienumerator

I'm trying to pass a string from an IEnumerator to a void. but the string keeps coming out null :( here is my code: I'm new to this so please help Thanks all.

my Void

```
public void ResisterButton ()
{   
    //checked Username
    if (Username != "") {
        StartCoroutine (CheackDBUN (Username));
        Debug.LogWarning("User Data String in ResisterButton " + userDataString); // not work is empty :(


    // do stuff with text eg turn bool UN = true
```

more code not to do with this

and the IEnumerator

```
IEnumerator CheackDBUN(string UsernamePost ){
    WWWForm form = new WWWForm ();
    form.AddField ("usernamePost", UsernamePost);

    WWW userData = new WWW(checkUsernameURL, form);
    yield return userData;
    string userDataString = userData.text;
    Debug.LogWarning("User Data String in CheackDBUN " + userDataString); //Working has text
    yield return (userDataString);
}
```

the Mysql and php code is all working fine

Thanks hope that works if need to know more please ask

Comment: Your question is  confusing. You are not even passing `userDataString` to the function. You are passing `Username`. What's the issue here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to wait for the coroutine to finish before using the `userDataString` result. Even though you are not changing `userDataString` in `CheackDBUN` (which i assume was your intention) you can still probably see that `User Data String in ResisterButton` is logged before `User Data String in CheackDBUN`.

You can use a callback delegate to tell the coroutine what to do with `userDataString` once it's finished.

```
public void ResisterButton ()
{    
    if (Username != "")
    {           
        StartCoroutine(CheackDBUN(Username,
            (userDataString) =>
            {
                Debug.LogWarning("User Data String in ResisterButton " + userDataString); 
                // do stuff with text eg turn bool UN = true
            }
            ));
    }
}
```

```
IEnumerator CheackDBUN(string UsernamePost, Action<string> callback){
    WWWForm form = new WWWForm ();
    form.AddField ("usernamePost", UsernamePost);

    WWW userData = new WWW(checkUsernameURL, form);
    yield return userData;
    string userDataString = userData.text;
    Debug.LogWarning("User Data String in CheackDBUN " + userDataString); //Working has text
    callback(userDataString);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the void function accept a string like so:

```
public void ResisterButton (string str){
```

And then pass the user data string to it like this:

```
Debug.LogWarning("User Data String in CheackDBUN " + userDataString); //Working has text
ResisterButton(userDataString);
yield return (userDataString);
```